# Google cdn jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-cdn

This works:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I prefer the syntax:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1", {uncompressed:true});
</script>
```

While developing.

Q: Can I load jQuery mobile using the google.load command?

Comment: Side note jQm is on beta 1. As for you're question, does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably the Google Libraries API will only support libraies listed in its [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries), seeing that the [Google Loader API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/loader/#GoogleLoad) does not contain any information on including your own library links.

Therefore the conclusion would be that there is currently no way to include jQuery Mobile with the Google Loader. Have you considered alternatives such as [head.js](http://headjs.com/)?